# Vincular colores de mapa SVG con base de datos

Tags: php, html, svg

La cosa esta asi... tengo un sistema en el cual traigo informacion sobre viviendas de una base de datos y quiero que en un mapa SVG que realice se muestren de diferente color las DISPONIBLES, VENDIDAS y APARTADAS. Asi mismo que cuando cambie el estado de una de estas se actualice el color. Pienso que este codigo me puede ayudar, pero de verdad no se bien como implementarlo.

[como cambiar color de secciones de imagen svg?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/239494/como-cambiar-color-de-secciones-de-imagen-svg/262365#262365)

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si necesitas actualizar los valores de una base de datos necesitas un formulario y unos elementos input. En este ejemplo en el svg hay 3 solares y en el formulario, **en el mismo orden** hay 3 `<input type="number">` aunque probablemente quieras que sean `type="hidden"`

En el código utilizo números: 0 para solares disponibles, 1 para solares vendidos y 2 para los apartados.

```js
// el array de los polígonos
let polygons = Array.from(svg.querySelectorAll("polygon"));
// el array de los inputs
let inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input"));

//para cada polígono del array de los polígonos
polygons.forEach((p,i)=>{
    // recupera la clase de este polígono
    let laClase = p.getAttribute("class");
    // recupera el input correspondiente que tiene el mismo index en el array de los inputs
    let elInput = inputs[i];
    // el tipo de solar es el último caracter de la cadena de texto laClase
    let n = Number(laClase[laClase.length-1]);
    
    //cada vez que haces clic en el polígono
    p.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    // n crece
    n++
    // establece el valor de la clase del polígono
    p.setAttribute("class","solar" + n%3); 
    // establece el valor del atributo value del input correspondiente
    elInput.value = n%3;    
  })
})
```

```css
polygon.solar0{fill:green; }
polygon.solar1{fill:gold;}
polygon.solar2{fill:skyblue;}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="number"  value="1" disabled />
  <input type="number"  value="0" disabled/>
  <input type="number"  value="2" disabled/>
</form>

<svg id="svg" viewBox="300 1150 270 200">

    <polygon class="solar1" stroke="#000" 
             points="339 1265.26 351.666 1240.334 390.334 1227.223 408.334 1278.111 365 1294.111 346.556 1286.778"/>
    
    <polygon class="solar0" stroke="#000" points="390.334 1227.223 445.444 1209.89 463.307 1265.26 408.334 1278.111"/>
 
    <polygon class="solar2" stroke="#000" points="445.444 1209.89 502.777 1199 509 1258.334 493.765 1258.334 463.307 1265.26"/>


</svg>
```

Comment: Hey! Muchas gracias, voy a intentar con la opcion que me das. Si tengo alguna duda al respecto te estare molestando de nuevo ¿vale? :)